How to handle membership and event prerequisites
Question on how to best handle prerequisites edits for event registrations, etc. in CIVICRM. Here are some examples:

On an event registration form, I will have an age field where the person filling out the form needs to check that they are ages 13-18.  If they check that box, they must also answer another field that they have parental consent to attend.
If the person filling out the form is registering for a Level 2 training event, they must have completed the Level 1 training event.
If the person filling out the form is registering to staff a training event, they must have successfully completed that training event as an attendee.

Looking for best options to handle these kinds of scenarios.

Your first requirement could be implemented with the extension "Field Conditions" (conditional field) or with webforms if you are using Drupal.
The other prerequisites your are planning most likely require more complex customizations. I would recommend taking a look at the extensions RemoteEvents - it offers a framework that allows you to relatively easy alter your event workflows.
It relies on other extensions so and the setup can be a bit more complicated - let us know if you need support.
Finally keep in mind that user need to be authenticated in order to implement your checks - either by login or by a unique token.

agree - also if using Drupal webform i could see some ways of doing this eg via Groups of contacts (those who are staff or those already one Level 1) and then use the Groups Roles Synch to set their Drupal role, then based on that set the access to the Level 2 or Staff events based on Drupal roles. just a thought. but without knowing the CMS it will only ever be a thought.

I should have mentioned that...Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.2, PHP 8.1, hosted on Linode.  Given that, are the extensions you mention available fo the Joomla CMS?  I do not see them in my available extensions list.

Hi Margaret, while the CiviCRM extensions involved should work for joomla, the public forms currently require a Drupal system (there are Drupal modules that render the forms and manage data exchange with CiviCRMs API).

Thank you, Fabian and petednz - fuzion
